# Init text to speech in all activities?

Tags: android, init, text-to-speech

Let us say the android app have more than one activity and services.
Each of them uses Text to speech. I understand all these activities and services
run in the same process unless we explicitly specify to run in a separate process.
We know at a time only one is active.

If this is the case do we have any way of initializing Text to speech engine
in one activity and reference it in other activities/services?.

*example*

```
ptrTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
```

in one activity and reference it in other activities/services?

what is the best place to do this initialization?

in `oncreate` or `oninit` of the Text to Speech or onactivityresult of whether TTS is installed or not?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, TextToSpeech() is just another class. If you create an object in one activity, it will get destroyed when you move to another activity.
There are different ways to share the same object between activities , like passing them through intents.
In your case you could make an application class where you define ptrTTS, like this(not sure if it is correct though):

```
class MyApp extends Application {

  private TextToSpeech ptrTTS;

  public TextToSpeech getObject(){
    return ptrTTS;
  }
  public TextToSpeech setObject(TextToSpeech obj){
    ptrTTS = obj;
  }
}
```

And you choose your first Activity to initialize it.

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    ...
    TextToSpeech ptr = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    MyApp appState = ((MyApp)getApplicationContext());
    appState.setObject(ptr);
    ...
  }
}
```